# Pandas, Code to extract more than one column uniquely based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by, unique

I am trying to write a code using Pandas in python. I have a csv file which contains of many rows but has three columns. I want to extract two columns based on third column. The resulting file should be the subset of the original file which has all the unique rows. I tried writing a code I am positive it is correct it does works for two columns meaning one column is getting extracted based on the another. But I need to do it for more columns. "Permno" is the unique column and "ticker" is one of the three columns I want to extract.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sp_comp_date.csv')

group = df.groupby('permno')

df2 = group.apply(lambda x:x['ticker'].unique())

print(df2)


Output :

permno
10001.0       [MCO]
10002.0       [MEE]
10003.0       [FMC]
10004.0        [OI]
10005.0    [IR, TT]
             ...   
93132.0      [FTNT]
93159.0       [ESV]
93422.0       [QEP]
93429.0      [CBOE]
93436.0      [TSLA]
Length: 1017, dtype: object
```

Comment: You might be looking for the function [agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)